# MySQL point-in-time recovery

Tags: innodb, mysql

I have a system where I have binary-logging enabled and I perform a mysqldump (single-transaction, all InnoDB) nightly. If I wanted to perform a point-in-time recovery, how would I know at which point in the binary log to start rolling forward? For example.

bin-log.000001 contains all the change before, and after my dump.sql file. If I do:

```
mysql < dump.sql
```

To restore to the last full export and then roll forward to the latest point using:

```
mysqlbinlog bin-log.000001 | mysql
```

Will MySQL know the right place to start from?

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, a bit more research has led me [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-policy.html). Just in case anyone else was wondering.

Comment: Maybe better to read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/point-in-time-recovery.html

Comment: It was that document that got me asking the question! The issue I had was knowing exactly when to start the roll forward from. Using --single-transaction --master_data=2 and --flush-logs makes it all possible.

Answer (score 0):

See the usage of mysqlbinlog:

```
  --stop-datetime=name
                      Stop reading the binlog at first event having a datetime
                      equal or posterior to the argument; the argument must be
                      a date and time in the local time zone, in any format
                      accepted by the MySQL server for DATETIME and TIMESTAMP
                      types, for example: 2004-12-25 11:25:56 (you should
                      probably use quotes for your shell to set it properly).
```

Seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: This was going to be something I would try. It's just not quite exact enough for me. There are hundreds of writes a second on this DB. I'll be using mysqlbinlog --start-position=<number from the dump file> instead.

Comment: @dwjv Oh sorry, you wanted where to start, not where to end.  Yes, absolutely use the `--flush-logs` option of mysqldump.  Then you can simply choose which binary log file to start with, instead of which individual transaction.  The "point in time" terminology got me confused I think...